# How to extract a url from a string in Java?

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a string containing a short-code which looks like the one below:

```
some text...
[video url="http://www.example.com/path/to/my/video.ext"]
...some more text...
```

I want to be able to first check if the string contains that short-code and second extract the URL from it in Java (specifically Android).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try as:

```
   String str = "[video url=\"http://www.example.com/path/to/my/video.ext\"]";
    if (str.contains("url=\""))
    {
        int indexoff = str.indexOf("url=\"");
        int indexofff = str.indexOf("\"]");
        String strurl = str.substring(indexoff, indexofff - indexoff);
        strurl = strurl.Replace("url=\"", ""); //get url string here

    }
```

Comment: This what I used at last, but strangely it cut the string 7 characters short. So I had to add 7 to `indexofff - indexoff` manually!

Answer (score 2):

use this regex for checking and grabbing url:

```
\[\w+\s+url="(?<urllink>)[^"]*"\s*]
```

and get gorup named *urllink*

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "whatever"
Boolean myBool = url.contains("ate");
```

[String contains.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) Not sure what extract url means, but the string class has lots of useful functions.

Comment: Extracting the URL means I need that URL in a separate var.

Answer (score 0):

Android provides several function for this purpose. SOme of this are:

- http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

A **powerful** and **maintainable** manner it to [Java URL.class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), then, you can mix with Regex